# Magento 2.3 - Almost blank page after adding to shoppingcart

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.3

I've upgraded my Magento from 2.2.6 to 2.3, everything went well, but I got some errors.

The first thing I saw in the system.log was something with an attribute, I fixed that. But when I add a product to the shoppingcart I only get to see this:

[image]

Translated to English it says: view shipping costs and Tax

What could that be, yesterday I spend almost a day searching for the solution but nothing found :(

The system.log says this:

```
[2019-03-14 08:01:08] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-03-14 08:01:08] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-03-14 08:01:08] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-03-14 08:01:08] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-03-14 08:01:08] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' element cannot be added as child to 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-03-14 08:01:08] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2019-03-14 08:01:08] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-03-14 08:01:08] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-03-14 08:01:08] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'cart.summary' tries to reorder itself towards 'checkout.cart.totals.container', but their parents are different: 'cart.bottom.col2' and 'cart.summary' respectively. [] []
```

But I have no idea if that has something to do with adding to shoppingcart because every other page is showing normal.

Update:

These were the latest errors in the exception.log (they are fixed)

```
[2019-03-13 10:12:34] main.CRITICAL: No linked stock found {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No linked stock found at /home/bootm2/domains/bootkoffie2.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/GetStockBySalesChannel.php:55)"} []
[2019-03-13 11:58:31] main.CRITICAL: No linked stock found {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No linked stock found at /home/bootm2/domains/bootkoffie2.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/GetStockBySalesChannel.php:55)"} []
[2019-03-13 12:00:05] main.CRITICAL: No linked stock found {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): No linked stock found at /home/bootm2/domains/bootkoffie2.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Price/Action/Full.php:163, Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No linked stock found at /home/bootm2/domains/bootkoffie2.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/GetStockBySalesChannel.php:55)"} []
[2019-03-13 12:10:04] main.CRITICAL: No linked stock found {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): No linked stock found at /home/bootm2/domains/bootkoffie2.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Price/Action/Full.php:163, Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No linked stock found at /home/bootm2/domains/bootkoffie2.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/GetStockBySalesChannel.php:55)"} []
```

Comment: check the exception.log , i think there is an error.

Comment: it seems an issue with a third party extension

Comment: @AnandOntigeri I've updated the question with the results in the exception.log

Comment: Try going into Stores > Inventory > Sources and adding in a source. Maybe call it your business name, then fill in a country and zip value.

Then, try going into Stores > Inventory > Stocks. Call it "Default Stock" and apply it to all websites (if multi store) and hit save.

After that, see if the issue remains.

Comment: @n00bly working or not?

Comment: @RakeshDonga Nope, not working :(

Comment: I already fixed the issue for the stock yesterday. That's not a problem anymore.

Comment: but you can try again this way

Comment: Hi @RakeshDonga, Yes I did again 20 minutes ago, but I didn't solve the issue.